# Recognizes the Username but Not the Password

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I've set up a database with dummy accounts in it.  My login page is able to identify the **Username** but *not* the **Password**.  I've double-checked the Passwords and they're correct.  Not sure why it only sees the Username.  Please advise.

My database looks like this:
**UserID**     **UserName**                 **Password**         **LastName**       **FirstName**       **Email**
2               barb@hotmail.com     coo1Talk            Lee                  Barb                  barb@hotmail.com
3               esther@hotmail.com  k1dd13              Tan                   Esther               esther@hotmail.com

And here is my code-behind file:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class SignIn
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
    Protected Sub signinBTN_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim sConnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TrackTicketsConnectionString2").ConnectionString)
    sConnection.Open()

    Dim cmdS As String = "Select count(*) from Users where UserName='" + usernameTXTBOX.Text + "' AND Deleted='N'"

    Dim cmdCheckUser As New SqlCommand(cmdS, sConnection)
    Dim num As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
    If num = 1 Then
        Dim cmdS1 As String = "Select * From Users WHERE UserName='" + usernameTXTBOX.Text + "' AND Deleted='N' AND Password='" + passwordTXTBOX.Text + "'"
        Dim pass As New SqlCommand(cmdS1, sConnection)
        Dim password As String = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

        If password = passwordTXTBOX.Text Then
            Session("Ticket") = usernameTXTBOX.Text
            Response.Redirect("mysupport.aspx")
        Else
            userCOMPARELBL.Visible = True
            userCOMPARELBL.Text = "Password is incorrect."
        End If
    Else
        userCOMPARELBL.Visible = True
        userCOMPARELBL.Text = "Username is incorrect."
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

The result I'm expecting is that the user can successfully login and be redirected to another page named support.aspx .

Comment: Some code would help?

Comment: Please post code aswell as a more complete description of the problem : what is expected and what is the current result. It is very unclear what the problem is exactly.

Comment: When you say "is able to identify" do you mean that the code-behind for the page is not receiving the password value back from the form? Are they actually getting as far as the database? How are you passing the values to the database? Please edit extra detail into your question.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use parameters.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Can you kindly elaborate?  Thanks!

Comment: When you construct queries using string concatenation from user input people can enter strings that end up being part of the executed query. (e.g. enter a username of `';DROP TABLE Users--` and the query becomes `Select count(*) from Users where UserName='';DROP TABLE Users--' AND Deleted='N'`)

Comment: @Esther: Watch the link in my answer. Jeff Atwood has posted a humorous and informing blog post about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I know it's off topic but...**[Use Parameterized queries!!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)**

2) Is the Deleted set to 'N' on the database?

Deleted='N'

3) Now, if your password matches your textbox, you're redirecting the support. I assume that is not the intended behaviour.

Code now:

```
   If password = passwordTXTBOX.Text Then
            Session("Ticket") = usernameTXTBOX.Text
            Response.Redirect("mysupport.aspx")
        Else
            userCOMPARELBL.Visible = True
            userCOMPARELBL.Text = "Password is incorrect."
        End If
```

Corrected:

```
If password.Equals(passwordTXTBOX.Text) Then
              userCOMPARELBL.Visible = True
            userCOMPARELBL.Text = "Password is incorrect."
        Else
   Session("Ticket") = usernameTXTBOX.Text
            Response.Redirect("mysupport.aspx")

        End If
```

Comment: It works!  And yes, the Deleted is set to 'N' on the database.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I've another question I hope you can help me.  It's actually related to the same thing I'm working on.  Please view at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904170/not-knowing-how-to-display-username-after-login) .

Comment: No worried. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm self-teaching myself and it's hard to know where to start.  Some days I feel like I know what I'm doing and some days not.

Comment: Please, if you've a chance, please help me with a problem located at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904170/not-knowing-how-to-display-username-after-login).  Thanks!