# Not Knowing How to Display Username After Login

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I’m still stumbling with this page over and over again.  Just couldn’t get the user’s **Username** (using email as the username) to display on `mysupport.aspx` page after she’s successfully logged in.  The result should look like this **with the email showing** but it is not retrieving anything:
**Email:**  barb@hotmail.com

Being an amateur, I know I’m missing a big piece of the puzzle but I don’t know what.  Am I using the **mailLBL.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString()** wrongly?  Below are the code-behind:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class mysupport
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim sConnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TrackTicketsConnectionString2").ConnectionString)
    sConnection.Open()

    Dim cmdS As String = "Select Email from Users Where Deleted='N'"
    Dim cmdCheckmail As New SqlCommand(cmdS, sConnection)

    If Session("Ticket") IsNot Nothing Then
        mailLBL.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString()
    Else
        Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx")
    End If

End Sub
Protected Sub signinBTN_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("Ticket") = Nothing
    Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx")
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help and guidance is truly appreciated!

Comment: You are never actually executing your Command (cmdCheckmail) and you don't have an SqlDataAdapter nor an SqlDataReader or DataTable to hold the results. Even if you did execute the command, where does Session("Ticket") get populated?

Comment: @HardCode: Thanks for pointing out the issues in my codes.  I'll have to do more research on this.  Pardon my ignorance.  I've a page called mysupport.aspx, which I thought where Session("Ticket") would be populated on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do first is study these links:

- [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [How to use Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There are several things wrong with this code.

Old Code:

```
Dim cmdS As String = "Select Email from Users Where Deleted='N'"
Dim cmdCheckmail As New SqlCommand(cmdS, sConnection)

If Session("Ticket") IsNot Nothing Then
    mailLBL.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString()
Else
    Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx")
End If
```

Corrected Code:

```
  If Session("Ticket") Is Nothing Then
    Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx")
  Else
    Dim cmdS As String = "Select Email from Users Where Deleted='N' AND Username=@Username"
    Dim cmdCheckEmail as new SqlCommand(cmdS, sConnection)
    cmd.AddParameters(new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session("Ticket")
    Dim obj as Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    If obj isNot Nothing
      mailLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(obj)
    End If
  End
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Will definitely look up the links you provided.  I replaced my wrong codes and it's saying "`cmd` is not declared. It may be inaccessable due to its protection level."  Can you advise?  THANKS!!!

Comment: That usually happens, if you try to use a variable outside of its defined block. So in the corrected code you can't use cmdCheckEmail after the "End If". I hope that's understandable.

Comment: This question may not be relevant.  How do I contact you if I need your help in the future?

Comment: I am sure the other users can help you too. And if you don't get an answer you can comment to me like you just did ;)

Comment: Cool!  I need all the help I can get.

Comment: I need help on this and haven't got any answer.  Can you kindly help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988237/specified-arguments-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-index)