# Specified arguments was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index

Tags: vb.net, gridview

This was the original line in code-behind **(CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox))** and it didn't work.  After that, I changed it to **row.Cells(1)** and received the above error when attempting to update a field in GridView.  Here're the aspx markups:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
     DataKeyNames="TicketID" DataSourceID="historySqlDataSource" ForeColor="#333333" 
     GridLines="None" Width="828px" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
     OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
              <Columns>
                 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketID" HeaderText="TicketID" 
                  InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TicketID" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="DateCreated" 
                  SortExpression="DateCreated" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="FullName" 
                  SortExpression="FullName" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketType" HeaderText="TicketType" 
                  SortExpression="TicketType" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
                  SortExpression="Subject" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" 
                  SortExpression="Message" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                  SortExpression="Status" />
              </Columns>
                 <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And below are the code-behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim dt = CType(Session("dt"), DataTable)

    'if your current DataSource be in Session
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.Cells(1).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("DateCreated") = (CType(row.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("FullName") = (CType(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketType") = (CType(row.Cells(4).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Subject") = (CType(row.Cells(5).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Message") = (CType(row.Cells(6).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Status") = (CType(row.Cells(7).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text

    Session("dt") = dt
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1
    BindData()

End Sub

Private Sub BindData()

    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: What didn't work with `Cells(0)`? Are you sure `Cells(7)` exists? You appear to be missing a column in `dt` for `DataField="Email"`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: With Cells(0), the error stated **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlLinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'**.  And you're right, I just noticed that I don't want the `DataField="Email"`.  Does it matter if one of my fields in the database is **Null**?

Comment: The Cells(0) problem is understandable :) Does it work now that you have removed the Email datafield? For Null values, you can do a web search for `vb.net datatable database null value` to get a few suggestions if you find it is a problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: No, it's still not working after the Email datafield was removed.  I commented out the line of code `dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text` and the error about being unable to cast object of type... applies to the 2nd line of code for DateCreated.  Can you kindly show me codes to convert this **("DateCreated") = (CType(row.Cells(1).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text** to a Date since it's not Text?  Thanks!

Comment: Please see the "Which method do I call?" section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Thanks for the link.  I commented out the 1st two lines for TicketID and DateCreated (same error appears) after debugging.  I'm beginning to think `dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text` is not working for all.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Please help as I'm stumped on this.

Comment: If you create a new variable for `(CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text` so that it is on a separate line, it will be easier to see if that is the problem or if `dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID")` is the problem. Also, have you checked that `e.RowIndex` is valid?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: What else can I use besides `e.RowIndex`?  Can you please advise?  I'm really new with this.  Initially, I used GridView directly off of VS2010 but it wasn't updating so I changed to the current code-behind to update and edit rows.

Comment: What I meant was that e.RowIndex might have a value of -1, which of course would not work. You're going to have to step through your code with the debugger and look more closely at which variables are giving you a problem.